# Can you disable a code signature check?

Tags: macos, code-signing

I wrote [a patch/utility](http://www.thebitguru.com/projects/iTunesPatch) that disables OS X's default functionality of starting iTunes when the play button is pressed.  This utility basically modifies the Remote Control Daemon (`rcd`) and comments out the Apple Script command to start iTunes.  This has worked fine until 10.7, but with 10.8 `rcd` now has code signature.  The patch now causes `Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)` after the executable is patched.

Obviously, the code signature checking is working as designed, but I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on what options I might have.  Is there a legit way to turn off this check on a single executable?  I have tried turning of GateKeeper, but that, understandably, didn't do it.

Any other suggestions for disabling the play button?

Comment: for signing you need to do this: sudo codesign -f -s - /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd

Comment: Thanks user48986, that did it.  I have updated the utility.

Comment: I have updated the utility, but can you (user48986) "answer" this question so you get the credit :)  Apparently I can't mark a comment as an answer.

Comment: Hilariously, I came to this answer, while solving *the exact same problem* in *the exact same way*, not realizing somebody (you) had had the same idea and already done the same thing. Thanks, both to user48986, and @thebitguru. :P

Answer (score 6):

I got the patch to work after running `sudo spctl --master-disable`. I don't know if there is any way to use spctl to target only rcd though.

Replacing the code signature with an ad-hoc identity with `sudo codesign -f -s - /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/` didn't seem to work. Edit: but as mentioned by user48986, it works if you specify the path to the executable, like `sudo codesign -f -s - /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd`.

Comment: Thanks!  I think maybe the only way is to use rcd from an older version of OS X :|

Answer (score 3):

To fix the signature of for example MirrorPro:

```
sudo codesign -f -s - /Applications/MirrorPro.app/Contents/MacOS/MirrorPro
/Applications/MirrorPro.app/Contents/MacOS/MirrorPro: replacing existing signature
```